# Native MongoDB query joining 2 tables using ObjectID as foreign field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I have a mongo database that I didn't create, but need to extract some additional data from.  I have access to the database, and can look at and query the tables, but I have been unable to join two tables to provide all the necessary information in my query output.

I have 2 tables that I am interested in. First Setting, which has documents that looks like this (truncated):

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aff382669153dc20edf945a"),
   "key" : "mgmt",
   "site_id" : "5aff382669153dc20edf9456",
   "advanced_feature_enabled" : false,
   "auto_upgrade" : true
}
```

and site, that looks like this (truncated):

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aff382669153dc20edf9456"),
   "desc" : "Joe's Crab Shack",
}
```

`site_id` in the `setting` table is a foreign key that refers to the hex component `_id` in the `site` table.
I would like the output to resemble this, but I have been unsuccessful:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aff382669153dc20edf9456"),
"desc" : "Joe's Crab Shack",
"setting" : [
                "_id" : ObjectId("5aff382669153dc20edf945a"),
                "key" : "mgmt",
                "site_id" : "5aff382669153dc20edf9456",
                "advanced_feature_enabled" : false,
                "auto_upgrade" : true
            ]
}
```

I would like to be able to do only a database query, currently using Robo 3T, and not have to resort to scripting or programming.  The closest that I have been able to get to the desired outcome is below.  This query returns the `site` documents, with all the `setting` documents that don't have a `site_id` foreign key.

```
db.site.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "setting",
        localField:"_id.str",
        foreignField:"site_id",
        as: "setting"
    }
}
])
```

I'm sure that I am missing something simple, but I am very new to MongoDB, and am a little lost due to the terminology differences between SQL and Mongo.  For any that are wondering, the database is actually the back end for a large, multisite Ubiquiti controller, and I am looking to create "reports" that provide more insight to devices that require upgrades, what settings don't meet our "default" configuration, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If `site_id` in `setting` collection is of type `ObjectId`, then you can try this

```
db.site.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "setting",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "site_id",
      as: "setting"
    }
  }
])
```

and you can test it here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CEy_UtsDa5V)

If `site_id` is of type `string`, then you cannot do that lookup, as `_id` and `site_id` should be matched in type too (`ObjectIds`), so you can change the `setting` schema to make the `site_id` of type `ObjectId` and refers to `site` schema

instead of this

```
site_id: String
```

use this

```
site_id: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'site' }
```

---

### Update

If site_id is a string and you are not able to change the setting schema, then we can do some work around

we can add a new property to the site document in the aggregate pipeline, which will store the _id of the document but as a string not ObjectId

something like this

```
db.site.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      siteIdString: { // this is the stringified version of the _id
        $toString: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "setting",
      localField: "siteIdString", // then use this string id in lookup stage
      foreignField: "site_id",
      as: "setting"
    }
  }
])
```

you can test it here [Mongo Playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9fRVtS7hjho)

hope it helps

Comment: @MohammedYoursy Unfortunately, i can't control the schema, it is a vendor supplied software.  Is there a way to check and see what types the fields are?

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle test_id as a string, could you check it?